# Django-mptt filter child from django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-mptt, django-filter

I have used django-mptt to represent my hierarchical data. To get the data from database table I have used following code from my template.

```
{% load mptt_tags %}
{% recursetree nodes %} 
{{ node.name }}
{% endrecursetree %}
```

Now I want to filter children by the id and I need **only one immediate child** to display in my template.how can I do this from my template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`level` property and [get_previous_sibling](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/models.html#get-previous-sibling) can be used to achieve this:

```
{% load mptt_tags %}

{% recursetree nodes %}

  {% if node.level == 0 %}
    {# first level #}
    {{ node.name }}
  {% elif not node.get_previous_sibling %}
    {# first child #}
    {{ node.name }}
  {% endif %}

  {{ children}}
{% endrecursetree %}
```

Please note that `get_previous_sibling` call will trigger db query.